# How to calculate and format time left for each downloading file using webclient?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the part that calculate the time left to download the current file:

```
// Calculate time left
if (e.BytesReceived > 0 && e.BytesReceived < e.TotalBytesToReceive)
{
    double downloadRate = e.BytesReceived / timeElapsed.TotalSeconds;
    double remainingBytes = totalBytes - bytesIn;
    double timeLeftInSeconds = remainingBytes / downloadRate;

    if (timeLeftInSeconds > 0)
    {
        TimeSpan timeLeft = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeLeftInSeconds);

        // Display time left
        lblTimeLeftReporter.Text = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", timeLeft.Hours, timeLeft.Minutes, timeLeft.Seconds);
    }
}
```

The result is that much of the time I see on the label 00:00:00 and the only value that get update is the rightest end zero change in range between 1 and 2 sometimes more.

and what I wanted it should like a timer or something else formatted nice that will estimate and display counting back the time left to download.

it's updating very fast the last milliseconds?)

in the screenshot you can see the 6 but it's not seconds, it's more milliseconds or so.
and I also noticed that when the file gets downloaded almost to the half then the time left label showing only 00:00:00 until the end of the file download.

it' not calculating and showing the real estimate time left to download. downloading 1 GB file at least should take some seconds if not minute/s

[image: time left]

This is how I make the calculations:

```
void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double bytesIn = e.BytesReceived;
    double totalBytes = e.TotalBytesToReceive;
    double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;

    // Update progress bar
    progressBar1.Value = (int)Math.Truncate(percentage);

    // Calculate download speed
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan timeElapsed = now - lastProgressUpdateTime;

    if (timeElapsed.TotalMilliseconds > 500)  // Update speed every 500 milliseconds
    {
        long bytesSinceLastUpdate = e.BytesReceived - lastProgressUpdateBytes;
        double speedInBytesPerSecond = bytesSinceLastUpdate / timeElapsed.TotalSeconds;

        // Fix the negative problem
        if (speedInBytesPerSecond < 0)
        {
            speedInBytesPerSecond = 0;
        }

        // Display download speed
        lblSpeedReporter.Text = FormatBytes(speedInBytesPerSecond) + "/s";

        lastProgressUpdateTime = now;
        lastProgressUpdateBytes = e.BytesReceived;
    }

    // Display downloaded size
    lblSizeReporter.Text = string.Format("{0} / {1}", FormatBytes(bytesIn), FormatBytes(totalBytes));

    // Calculate time left
    if (e.BytesReceived > 0 && e.BytesReceived < e.TotalBytesToReceive)
    {
        double downloadRate = e.BytesReceived / timeElapsed.TotalSeconds;
        double remainingBytes = totalBytes - bytesIn;
        double timeLeftInSeconds = remainingBytes / downloadRate;

        if (timeLeftInSeconds > 0)
        {
            TimeSpan timeLeft = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeLeftInSeconds);

            // Display time left
            lblTimeLeftReporter.Text = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", timeLeft.Hours, timeLeft.Minutes, timeLeft.Seconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not calculate time-left based on your download speed in the last 500ms but instead take the average since the start of the download.

Comment: Your problem likely comes in your calculation of `downloadRate` where you're divinding `e.BytesReceived` (from the start) with `timeElapsed.TotalSeconds` (resets every 500ms, so anywhere between `0.0` to `0.5`).